# What's the best way to setup a docker based cluster on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ecs

We are building a small micro service architecture which we would like to deploy to AWS.
The number of services is growing, so we need solution that allows scaling (horizontal).

What's the best way to build this on AWS? We don't have too much experience with docker, we used EC2 based stuff in the past.

I'm thinking about something like:

- Use ECR, create a private docker repository. We push release images there.
- Use ECS to automatically deploy those images.

Is this correct? Or should we go for Kubernetes instead? Which one is better?

Our needs:

- Automated deployments based on docker images
- Deploy to test and prod environments
- Prod cluster should be able to handle multiple instances of certain services with load balancing.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Use ECS, is much more simple than Kubernetes on AWS (EKS). Also, if you can use Fargate, is great to offload the management. If you can learn from scratch, use ECS on EC2. Good luck!

Comment: Your question is soliciting opinions, which is off-topic for this site. If there was only one truly "best" service, then there would be no reason for the other services to exist. The best service if you want the ability to easily move to other cloud vendors later would probably be EKS. The best service for absolute simplicity and ease of use might be Elastic Beanstalk. I'm personally a fan of ECS+Fargate.

Comment: Thanks guys for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS container service team member here. Agreed with others that answers may potentially be very skewed to personal opinions. If you come in with good AWS knowledge but no container knowledge I would suggest ECS/Fargate. Note that deploying on ECS would require a bit of CloudFormation mechanics because you need to deploy a number of resources (load balancers, IAM roles, etc) in addition to ECS tasks that embeds your containers. It could be daunting if not abstracted.

We have created a few tools that allows you to offload some of that boiler plating. In order of what I would suggest for your use case:

- Copilot which is a CLI tool that can prepare environments and deploy your app according to specific patterns. Have a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-aws-copilot/)
- Docker Compose integration with ECS. This is a new integration we built with Docker that allows you to start from a simple Docker Compose file and deploy to ECS/Fargate. See [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/).
- CDK is a sw development framework to define your AWS infrastructure as code. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html). [These are the specific CDK ECS patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-patterns-readme.html) if you want to go down that route.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know these tools exist! Thank you.
One more question: costs are important for my manager. ECS with EC2 would be the economical option, right? Fargate seems to be expensive. What's the most cost effective way of using ECS?

Comment: As per all managed services Fargate has a small price premium over comparable EC2 capacity. [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/theoretical-cost-optimization-by-amazon-ecs-launch-type-fargate-vs-ec2/) article covers the cost model and [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/saving-money-pod-at-time-with-eks-fargate-and-aws-compute-savings-plans/) other article goes more into the TCO analysis (the last blog refers to EKS/Fargate but the concepts are similar for ECS/Fargate).

Comment: I tried the copilot path and it works nicely. I can see that the service running in the cloud. However, it doesn't print any URL. It just says my app has been deployed. Where can I find the public URL? It's an app which has only a single service right now, it's. backend service (API).

Comment: I don't have a copilot environment handy right now but `copilot app show` should describe the app (and output its endpoint).

Comment: No that prints only the envs, services and pipelines. It prints the URI too, but that'e empty. @mreferre